# Elasticsearch initial configuration in Java code or in external script?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, elasticsearch

I am learning Elasticsearch and I have started a new project. Now I wonder where I should add the initial code for creating the mappings etc. Would you create an external script which holds the different cURL commands and then run that, or have for example a own package in the Java project where you have the configuration code and then run it when you need to? Which approach is the most appropriate and why?

Mapping that I want to try with XContentBuilder

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
            "message" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "store" : "yes",
                "index" : "analyzed",
                "null_value" : "na"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to have it in java:

```
public void putMappingFromString(String index, String type, String mapping) {

    IndicesAdminClient iac = getClient().admin().indices();
    PutMappingRequestBuilder pmrb = new PutMappingRequestBuilder(iac);
    pmrb.setIndices(index);
    pmrb.setType(type);
    pmrb.setSource(mapping);
    ListenableActionFuture<PutMappingResponse> laf = pmrb.execute();
    PutMappingResponse pmr = laf.actionGet();
    pmr.getAcknowledged();

}
```

You can also get the mapping for an index from the cluster state (indirectly):

```
public String getMapping(String index, String type) throws EsuException {
    ClusterState cs = getClient().admin().cluster().prepareState().setFilterIndices(index).execute().actionGet().getState();
    IndexMetaData imd = cs.getMetaData().index(index);

    if (imd == null) {
        throw new EsuIndexDoesNotExistException(index);
    }

    MappingMetaData mmd = imd.mapping(type);

    if (mmd == null) {
        throw new EsuTypeDoesNotExistException(index, type);
    }

    String mapping = "";
    try {
        mapping = mmd.source().string();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        mapping = "{ \"" + e.toString() + "\"}";
    }
    return mapping;
}
```

This allows for versioning your mappings along with your source code if you store your mappings as a resource on your class path

Comment: So you ave a own main method or some other way to execute the configuration once when you need it?

Comment: Yes.  The key point being that developers should have a single, consistent way to interact with elastic search, whether it's via curl or by a Java framework that would include the methods above.

Comment: Alright, so the next question is: Where did you learn that you use those classes? I don't understand where you find any good resources on ElasticSearch?

Comment: I used stack overflow, google and the source code.  It's for this reason that I want to hide the hard-to-find details from my platform users in my dev org so they can develop apps faster.  Even if it's just for you, you'll find that you'll be making these API calls over and over again and that's reason enough to package them this way.

Comment: Okey, thank you. Odd that Elasticsearch doesn't provide better documentation of their software.

Comment: What do you use for creating the mappings? String, Map, XContentBuilder..? Could you please give an example with the XContentBuilder if that is what you use? I have updated the question with what I want to add mapping for.